# Automatically converting JSON bytes from RabbitMQ queue to object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-amqp

Is it possible to configure `Spring AMQP` so it will automatically convert messages from queue (which are essentially `JSON` strings) into the objects of desired type?

What I have tried so far:

1) My cfg:

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter">
   <rabbit:listener ref="foo" method="listen" queue-names="test_queue"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
<bean id="foo" class="foo.FooListener"/>
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter"/>
```

2) My listener `FooListener` has method `listen(FooMessage foo) { ... }`

and

3) My `FooMessage` is just simple POJO and messages in my `test_queue` are just serialized instances of `FooMessage` in `JSON` format.

So it doesn't work, Spring claims for `listen(byte[] msg)` method:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: foo.FooListener.listen([B)`.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually this thing works like a charm with `Spring AMQP` even prior version 1.6. The problem was with incorrect `content-type` of my message, it was just `text/plain`.

If message with `json` is sent in appropriate way, say

```
template.convertAndSend("test_queue", "test_queue", new FooMessage("blablabla","blabla"));
```

with correctly setup `template`:

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"
                     connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
                     message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
                     />
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter"/>
```

so method `listen(FooMessage foo) { ... }` is invoked with automatically created object of type `FooMessage` from message.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RC1/reference/html/_reference.html#json-message-converter) for the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`.
And pay attention to the note:

> In versions prior to 1.6, if type information is not present, conversion would fail. Starting with version 1.6, if type information is missing, the converter will convert the JSON using Jackson defaults (usually a map).

So, independently of the target argument type of the POJO handler, the `MessageProperties` must contain `__TypeId__` information.

To meet your requirement consider to use `@RabbitListener` instead.

See the same section for news in the Spring AMQP 1.6.

Although feel free to raise a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we may consider some hooks for general `MessageListenerAdapter` where we know the method via `listener ref="foo" method="listen"` and, therefore, can infer the target argument type before conversion.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that in my way of listener configuration this is not yet possible?

Comment: So, the problem was with incorrect content-type of my message